Hypernymic term for what is being searched and what is being searched for?
What is a hypernymic term for "what is being searched" and "what is being searched for"?
Contextual examples...
In the old saying...

What is being searched is the haystack.
What is being searched for is the needle.

In a criminal investigation...

What is being searched is the crime scene.
What is being searched for is evidence.

In a library...

What is being searched are the shelves.
What is being searched for is a specific book.


You're looking for a single generic term to include the locations being searched and for the targets of the searches?

I doubt if there's a catch-all term for your examples.

depends on the context - corpus, domain, field, region, time span.

Are you looking for two words such as  location and target?

You could use search parameters for a formal way of referring to both, although the term could include who or what is doing the search, the time, location, etc.

There are a lot of different terms for both of these but I don't think one would fit all areas. For instance, there's a difference between searching a physical place and some other realm (a mathematical space, the internet, your memory). And between searching for a particular object (my lost watch, the Holy Grail, a missing person) or for something in general (gold, evidence, the meaning of life, etc). Unless you use a very generic term like "the searched" and "the search area/field/realm".

'Generic' really implies 'covering all of a large/largish range of members of a (therefore large/largish) set', not just two: generic: relating to or characteristic of a whole group or class [M-W]

You need to give a real-life example of the way in which you will use these words.

Why is there this misguided notion that antithetical terms can be described with one term? Over and over we get these questions...

How about Index?
As a collective noun, it can mean a group of searchable items or data. "I will be perusing the library index". While it is uncommon to define certain wholes as indicies such as your crime scene and haystack, once the individual parts are catalogued, the sum of the work can be called an index.
As a singular noun, index can mean a single item out of a whole. "The index entry for an address", "the index for a database row", "the index number for a book".
